# mongoose find method returns an empty array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have an issue.

I should use the mongoose `find()` method for some queries. While using the `find()` method, when I give filter find method works but it doesn't give me value/values.

```
const messages = await MessageSchema.find({sessionId: sessionId}, {__v: 0, _id: 0, updatedAt: 0}).exec();
```

The above code is my find method. This code gives me as value, empty array. []

But in this code,

```
const messages = await MessageSchema.find({}, {__v: 0, _id: 0, updatedAt: 0}).exec();
```

give me an array and all of the messages are in the array.

But I should use filtering.

This is my message Schema.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    participant_name: {type: String},
    message: {type: String},
    sessionId: {type: String},
    participantId: {type: Object}
}, {
    timestamps: true
});


module.exports = mongoose.model("Message", schema)
```

Could you help me please?

Comment: check your MongoDB collection that exists any document with the `sessionId`

Comment: General curiosity...what is the idea behind `{__v: 0, _id: 0, updatedAt: 0}`?  Have you tried omitting this and calling `MessageSchema.find({sessionId: sessionId}).exec();`?

Comment: According to [this](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find) documentation, the second parameter of the find method is optional fields to return. But `__v, _id, updatedAt` variables are not in the model scheme. Remove the second parameter and try again.

Comment: @Heartbit yes, i check my mongoDb schema. sessionId is exist in my schema.

Comment: @Faruk in this mongoose schema, they field default coming.

Comment: @minlopalis 
Yes, I tried the way you mentioned. But doesnt work.

Comment: Maybe `sessionId` is null or undefined?

Comment: @Heartbit  when my query is changed like const messages = await MessageSchema.find({sessionId: sessionId}); it still doesn't work. Still give me an empty array. 

These are my logs.
Session ID** : ->  ses_S1fQCGlBZr
MESSAGES:->
 []

Comment: @Faruk look at my logs. :D

Session ID** : ->  ses_S1fQCGlBZr
MESSAGES:->
 []

Comment: I mean check your collection inside db not your schema

Comment: @Heartbit interestingly, i check in my collection. :D insomuch as, i check sessionId that coming in db, they are match. :D

Comment: Is this condition true -> `seesionId === collection.sessionId`?

Comment: @Heartbit

This is my  terminal logs:
`GET MESSAGES Method
Session ID** : ->  ses_S1fQCGlBZr
MESSAGES:-> [ ]`

This is db collection record;
`sessionId: "ses_S1fQCGlBZr"`

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast your sessionId to Object id type in filtering.

how?

```
import { Types } from 'mongoose';

const messages = await MessageSchema.find({sessionId: Types.ObjectId(sessionId)}, {__v: 0, _id: 0, updatedAt: 0}).exec();
```

Comment: Firstly, thanks your answer.

But, i take another error.

`(node:7972) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters`.

Another case, sessionId is not my ObjectId. SessionId is another field in my document. ObjectId is different in my case.

Comment: can you give me type of sessionId using typeof sessionId?

Comment: or try casting in the same query up to String instead of ObjectId

Comment: The following output is my terminal output.

`Session Id:  ses_KZKvE6T5rn
Session Id typeı  string`

Comment: I changed my code with `const messages = await MessageSchema.find({sessionId: Types.String(sessionId)}, {__v: 0, _id: 0, updatedAt: 0}).exec();`

When i run above code, i have an error.

`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Types.String is not a function
    at Service.getMessages (C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\media-server\app\components\session\service\Session.js:255:26)   
    at Service.createSessionTerminateJob (C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\media-server\app\components\session\service\Session.js:202:10)`

Comment: not Types.String but only String(sessionId), is a basic Node js function

Comment: Didnt work ..... Still give me an empty array..

Comment: can you put in the question an example of object finded??